# splice() method works but array does not change after execution

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, session, express

I'm using express.js (node.js) to build an application. I have a products array declared as a session (req.session.products) in app.js folder.
Here's the POST route:

```
router.post('/remove-cart', (req, res, next) => {

    var product_id = req.body.product_id; //get product id from client

    console.log(req.session.products)

    var n = req.session.products.indexOf(product_id); //get position of product id in the array
    req.session.products.splice(n, 1); //remove it

    console.log(req.session.products)

});
```

At the end of the route it logs this when n = 0:

```
[ '1', '3', '3', '3', '3' ]
[ '3', '3', '3', '3' ]
```

This is what I'm expecting, however, this does not affect the main session (req.session.products) and doesn't sort of "save" it. Why?

Comment: how about `req.session.products = req.session.products.splice(n, 1)`

Comment: Assign it again to products.

Comment: @Cedric Hadjian you code is working fine in this block of code i guess your problem is somewhere else becouse you want to remove an item at 0 index and it removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real problem here is that **you are not returning the `req.session.products` array to your app**, you need to send it back in the response.

In the end of your `.post()` method write this line:

```
res.send(req.session.products);
```

Comment: @Shubham It was a typo, I was trying to write another thing then refactored the phrase and missed the `doesn't` part.

Comment: This still doesn't affect the original array. I'm sure it should but it isn't no idea why..

Comment: @CedricHadjian Maybe the `product_id` doesn't exist in the array. Wrap it inside an if statement.

Comment: It does! if req.body.product_id is 1 then n = 0 (first element) and the query works, but still doesn't affect the original array

Comment: @CedricHadjian That's because you are not sending back the array to your `app`, you need to write res.send(req.session.products);``  in the end. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Sure just did. By the way, req.session.products = req.session.products.splice(n, 1) was assigning the spliced element to the array, so req.session.products.splice(n, 1) without assigning it back worked perfectly. I only needed to res.send()! Thank you so much I just learned how res.send() works.

Comment: @CedricHadjian Glad it helps, Yes I misread the question in the first place, answer edited. :)